# Uncaught TypeError : cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have got a problem with the JavaScript of a Wordpress plug-in that I am using.

Here is my code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.extend($.slidewizard.prototype, {
        _options_default: function (opts) {
            return opts;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I've got a lot of JS/jQuery in my website and I think there is a conflict between them.
My console said:

> Uncaught TypeError : cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it means that `$.slidewizard` is not defined. Make sure you load the plugin before you run this code.

Answer (score 0):

slidewizard is not a part of jQuery, it is a wordpress plugin.

Where you have `$.slidewizard.prototype` you should be referencing the wordpress library that holds slidewizard instead of $ which is jQuery.

**EDIT: Unless this is a special version of jQuery implemented by wordpress that already implements slidewizard, in which case it will mean that the script doesn't actually contain an object called slidewizard.**

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your quick answer ! 

i don't know if it's a special version cause i just downloaded this plug-in. 
think problem is that i am using an old jQuery version for one of the plug.

Thank to you, will see that  :)